# Microsoft Teams Tab with MSAL sign in

Tags: .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

I've been working on getting a custom tab working in MS teams using MSAL.  I've been following the example here: https://github.com/nmetulev/teams-msal and I can generate a token.  I then try to forward this token to my API, where I build a security claim and call `SignInAsync()` to persist the cookie.

This then gets stored, and I forward to my standard page, but this does not page auth (I get unauthorized).  Is there something I'm missing that I need to be doing?

Auth Page

```js
 const signIn = () => {
        msalApp.acquireTokenRedirect(authenticationParameters);
    }

    const handleSignedIn = () => {
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
        microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess();
    }

    const handleSignedOut = (error) => {
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
        microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure(error);
    }

    const handleErrorReceived = (authError, accountState) => {
        console.log(authError, accountState);
        handleSignedOut({authError});
    }

    const handleTokenReceived = (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        handleSignedIn();
    }

    // MAIN
    const msalApp = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
    msalApp.handleRedirectCallback((response) => handleTokenReceived(response), (error, state) => handleErrorReceived(error, state));

    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
        authenticationParameters = {
            scopes: scopes,
            loginHint: context.loginHint
        };

        setTimeout(() => {
                attemptSilentSignIn().then(success => {
                    if (success) {
                        handleSignedIn();
                    } else {
                        signIn();
                    }
                });
            },
            4000);
    });
```

Sign In Page:

```js
  const attemptSilentSignIn = () => {
    renderLoading();
    if (msalApp.getAccount()) {
        msalApp.acquireTokenSilent({ scopes }).then((response) => {
            if (response && response.accessToken) {
                handleSignedIn(response.accessToken);
            } else {
                handleSignedOut();
            }
        }, () => {
            handleSignedOut();
        })
    } else {
        handleSignedOut();
    }

}

const signIn = () => {
    renderLoading();
    microsoftTeams.initialize(() => {
        microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
            url: window.location.origin + "/resources/TeamsAuthFlow.html",
            successCallback: () => attemptSilentSignIn(),
            failureCallback: (error) => renderError(error)
        });
    });
}

const handleSignedIn = (accessToken) => {
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => {
        var tenant = $("<input>").attr("id", "TenantId").attr("name", "TenantId").val(context.tid);
        var token = $("<input>").attr("id", "AuthToken").attr("name", "AuthToken").val(accessToken);
        var form = $("<form>").css("display", "none").attr("id", "target").attr("method", "POST").attr("action", "/api/TeamsTabSignIn").append(tenant).append(token).submit();
        $("body").append(form);
        $("#target").submit();
    });
}

const handleSignedOut = () => {
    renderSignedOutView();
}


// MAIN
let app = document.querySelector('.app');
const msalApp = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

attemptSilentSignIn();


let authenticationParameters = null;

const handleErrorReceived = (authError, accountState) => {
    console.log(authError, accountState);
    handleSignedOut({ authError });
}

const handleTokenReceived = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    handleSignedIn();
}
```

API Call

```cs
 TenantId = Context.Request.Form["TenantId"];
 AuthToken = Context.Request.Form["AuthToken"];
 var principal = await _authHelper.SetPlatformUser(TenantId, AuthToken);
 if (principal is ClaimsPrincipal cp)
 {
     await Context.SignInAsync("Cookies", cp, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });
     Response.Redirect("/app/teamspage/Ticket");
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a Bot Framework question. Can you explain why you used the Bot Framework tag?

Comment: Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/nmetulev/teams-msal)?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT that's the exact sample I linked in the question.  I can get the token, but cannot persist the cookie into my app

Comment: @KyleDelaney I tagged Bot Framework since that's what I'm using for chatting with the bot and such - if the tab for bots does not apply to botframework I'd be happy to remove the tag.

Comment: Could you please check this [example](https://github.com/ydogandjiev/taskmeow)? Try if that helps.